# Cannot access SQL Server through C# application

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

[image]

I am developing an application in C# in Visual Studio 2010 for connecting this application with SQL Server 2008R2 on local computer.

I have written a connection string file in my application. But when I try to access the database through config file by accessing the connection string it gives me an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I am sharing the snapshot of my SQL Server instance and also the config file so please let me know what is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="MyDbConn1"
     connectionString="Data Source=jahanzaib-pc\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Tawacal;User Id=sa;
 Password=123;"/>
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And code for accessing connection string.

```
constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyDbConn1"].ToString();
SqlConnection newcon = new SqlConnection(constr);
newcon.Open();
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? Winforms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET ? Also: are you **sure** that connection string is in your main app's `app.config` or `web.config`??

Comment: Side-note: you should **NEVER EVER** use the `sa` account - not even in development .....

Comment: Check this: `object myDbConn1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyDbConn1"];` - what are you getting? I suspect this will be `NULL` .....

Comment: i am developing a winform application. yes i have share the app config file. And  in respone of your third comment  i am  getting exception object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So obviously, there's no config or not the correct config, if accessing `.AppSettings[]` is already throwing an exception. Are you **100% sure** that this `app.config` is with the **main application** (and not with a class library project that your app uses) ?? Do you see a `MyApplication.exe.config` file in your `bin\debug` folder in your main application project when you run that app?

Comment: no i have place this config file in my winUI project main folder  .

Comment: @marc_s please tell me what is the issue?